# How to convert string from API and render in syncfusion control as word doc or sfdt format

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, typescript

I have a word document that I have saved locally as a string from syncfusion. I would like to use that
string to reproduce the document and display it in the syncfusion documentEditor.

I keep getting an error when I retrieve the string from the API and try to open the document in syncfusion. In addition,
the reason I am making reference to syncfusion control in afterViewInit is because `onInit` I am getting:

> documentEditor is not defined.

```
public async Task<string> ImportOffline(string file)
        {
            try
            {
                //Byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(file.Split(',')[1]); 
                Byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(file);

                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                Syncfusion.EJ2.DocumentEditor.FormatType type = Syncfusion.EJ2.DocumentEditor.FormatType.Docx;
                stream.Position = 0;
                //EJ2WordDocument document = EJ2WordDocument.Load(stream, Syncfusion.EJ2.DocumentEditor.FormatType.Docx);
                Syncfusion.EJ2.DocumentEditor.WordDocument document = Syncfusion.EJ2.DocumentEditor.WordDocument.Load(stream, Syncfusion.EJ2.DocumentEditor.FormatType.Docx);
                string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(document);
                document.Dispose();
                // stream.Dispose();
                return json;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            } 
            
          }


ngAfterViewInit(){
        this.container.toolbarItems = ["Undo", "Redo", "Table", "PageNumber", "Break", "Find"];
        this.container.showPropertiesPane = false;
          console.log(localStorage.getItem('currentstudentanswerdockey')); 
          /*this.documentFromBase64 = localStorage.getItem('currentstudentanswerdockey'); 
          var jsObject =
          {
              file: this.documentFromBase64
          };
          this.documentFromBase64 = localStorage.getItem('currentstudentanswerdockey');*/ 
          this.testService.getUrl(`${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentstudentanswerdockey'))}/convert-offlinestring`)
          .subscribe((data) => {
            console.log(data); 
            this.documentFromBase64 = data; 
            this.container.documentEditor.open(data)
          })  
      }
  
  



Below is code showing how the file is initially saved to local 
      
    

this.container.documentEditor.saveAsBlob('Docx').then((exportedDocument: Blob) => {
          let formData: FormData = new FormData();
          reader.readAsDataURL(exportedDocument);
          reader.onload = () => { 
          base64DataLocal = reader.result; 
          console.log(base64DataLocal);
          this.storageService.saveStudentAnswerDocLocal(base64DataLocal);
          };

        
      }
```